# How to access all values posted to PHP server

Tags: php, http

I first thought it was in the `$_POST` super global, but it isn't if values are included in the URL.

`$_REQUEST` did so and surprised me by not including cookies (reference http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php), and I later found that I am evidently using the default distribution php.ini file which does not contain the 'C' for cookies (reference http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.request-order).  I don't wish to use `$_REQUEST`, however, as it doesn't differentiate between a get request, and changing servers and php.ini files could cause a security concern.

What is the proper way to access all post values?

EDIT.  I added the `$real_post` part.  Is this the proper way to do so?

```
<?php
setcookie('cookie', 'COOKIE', time() + (86400 * 30), "/");

echo('$_GET<pre>'.print_r($_GET,1).'</pre>');
echo('$_POST<pre>'.print_r($_POST,1).'</pre>');
echo('$_COOKIE<pre>'.print_r($_COOKIE,1).'</pre>');
echo('$_REQUEST<pre>'.print_r($_REQUEST,1).'</pre>');
$real_post=($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')?array_merge($_GET,$_POST):array(); 
echo('$real_post<pre>'.print_r($real_post,1).'</pre>');
?>

<form action='postorget.php?get=GET' method='post'>
    <input type='text' name='post' value='POST'>
    <input type='submit'>
</form>
```

> $_GET
>
> Array (
>       [get] => GET )
>
> $_POST
>
> Array (
>       [post] => POST )
>
> $_COOKIE
>
> Array (
>       [cookie] => COOKIE )
>
> $_REQUEST
>
> Array (
>       [get] => GET
>       [post] => POST )

Comment: I'm curious - why do you need that?

Comment: @u_mulder  Adding logging functionality and wanted to keep track of all GET and POST values, and the results surprised me.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, your question is a little unclear. Parameters appended to the URL (as you mention in the beginning) are GET parameters, so they are contained in the `$_GET` superglobal. They simply are not POST variables. So what is your question here? You could combine `$_POST` and `$_GET` or, preferred, check for a desired parameter in *both* locations.

You can invest endless time into stuff like this, but a convenient approach might look like this:

```
$param = isset($_GET['param']) ? $_GET['param'] 
                               : (isset($_POST['param']) ? $_POST['param'] 
                                                         : null);
```

This line is just an example. It retrieves a parameter called 'param' from the super globals `$_GET` *or* `$_POST` and stores it in the variable `$params` in the local scope. This way you can access any parameter you are looking for regardless if it is sent as a GET or as a POST parameter. I often wrap that in a convenience function which also takes care of validating the parameters runtime value.

You could also wrap this example in an iteration loop:

```
$params = [
    'id'     => null, 
    'key'    => null, 
    'value'  => null, 
    'remark' => null
]; // just as examples
foreach ($params as $key=>$null) {
    // alternative 1: store the value of param $key in a single local scalar variable
    // this results in local variables $id, $key, $value, $remark, just as examples
    $$key = isset($_GET[$key]) ? $_GET[$key] 
                               : (isset($_POST[$key]) ? $_POST[$key] 
                                                      : null);
    // alternative 2: store the value of param $key in a general but local params array
    // this results in the above $params array, but filled with scalar values
    $params[$key] = isset($_GET[$key]) ? $_GET[$key] 
                                       : (isset($_POST[$key]) ? $_POST[$key] 
                                                              : null);
}
```

These are actually *two* examples. Obviously you need only one of the two statements shown inside the loop here. This depends on whether you prefer an array of params or separate local scalar variables.

---

If you are looking for a way to get *all* GET and POST parameters without actually knowing which that might be, then you have to combine the two super globals:

```
$params = array_merge($_GET, $_POST);
```

Note however that this is a very questionable architecture. It typically opens security holes.

Comment: It is my understanding that a GET and POST request can never happen simultaneously, thus I don't believe they are GET values, but truly POST values even though PHP shows them as GET variables.

Comment: You are right, that your request is either GET or POST, not both. But that does _not_ mean you cannot provide GET _and_ POST parameters. Maybe you should not, but you can.

Comment: Can be PUT/DELETE/OPTIONS though

Comment: @DarkBee That is certainly right, but not topic of this question :-)

Comment: This solution will only access half the values.  I "could" do something similar and merge the two, but this doesn't sound like the "proper" way to do so.

Comment: Why would that only access "half of the values"? Could you elaborate that statement? Explain what you mean by this? This is not meant to be *the* propper way, there is none. I suggested a convenience workaround you might require because of the way you create your POST requests. But as said: I do not see what parameters you would not get this way.

Comment: If something extra is included in the URL, then `$param` would only include those values and not the values in the `$_POST` array.  I am trying to access all values posted to PHP server.

Comment: Sorry, but you did not understand my lines. I will try to make them more clear, one minute...

Comment: I added some explanation to make it easier to understand the approach. Be sure that it _does_ work and that it _does_ allow you to access all parameters :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

$uVariables = array("GET" => $_GET, "POST" => $_POST, "COOKIES" => $_COOKIES, "SESSION" => $_SESSION);

and then use json_encode() for database storage. Should you later decide to build a log viewer you can just use json_decode() and get everything back in original state.